# Automatically refresh ListView from a checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListView that's bound to a simple array of objects (mainly getters / setters).  It shows after the main code has run as a simple report.  Initially the dialog just shows the items that changes.  I have "Show All Details" checkbox that the user can check to see all items.  I have a MultiTriggger setup on the checkbox and the "ZeroChanged" property.  The issue seems to be that the ListView needs to be told to refresh when the checkbox changes state so that the MultiTrigger will then adjust the Visibility Value = "Collapsed" action.  I'm starting to think that I'll need some supporting C# code to process the checkbox and then refresh the ListView.  The array of objects doesn't change, it's fixed output from the main program.  The check box defaults to false  Is this possible with just XAML?

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=_showAllDetailsChkBox}" Value="False" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding ZeroChanged}" Value="True" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` properly in your viewmodels, including the items in the ListView. Make sure all viewmodel properties raise `PropertyChanged` when their values change. Use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List` or an array. Bind to the `IsChecked` property of the checkbox instead of the CheckBox itself : `{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=_showAllDetailsChkBox}`. You don't need any special C# code to refresh anything if all the bindings are correct and the change notifications are being raised in the viewmodels.

Comment: The Checkbox in in a stackpanel in the main grid of the screen.  There's a couple of other buttons in the stackpanel (Close and misc functions...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bind to the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox`, the `Visibility` property of the `ListView` should get set as soon as you check or uncheck the `CheckBox`. You are missing a binding path:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=_showAllDetailsChkBox}" Value="False" />
<Condition Binding="{Binding ZeroChanged}" Value="True" />
```